# ? in ActiveRecord select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a where statement, you can use variables like:

```
Order.where('employee_id = ?', params[:employee_id])
```

I'm trying to accomplish something similar with a select, but it's not working:

```
Order.select('amount FROM line_items WHERE employee_id = ? AS employee_line_items', params[:employee_id])
=> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
=> LINE 1: ...ployee_id" = ? AS employee_line_items, 1
```

What's going on here? Is it possible to use `?` in select statement? If not, how can you insert an escaped sql string here? I'd like to just use `#{params[:employee_id]}`, but this bit of code would be vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split your query and chain it:

```
Order.select('amount FROM line_items').where(['WHERE employee_id = ?', params[:employee_id]])
```

And also based on this [question](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18195.1038530280@sss.pgh.pa.us), I believe you cannot use `AS` in `WHERE` clause, only when selecting fields (and you can't use them in `WHERE` in any case)

Check the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) to understand how `select` works on ActiveRecord models

Comment: It is possible to use AS in conjunction with FROM, even in a WHERE clause. Either way, thanks for the tip. It's good to know we simply can't use `?` here. Ended up going with `#{ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(params[:employee_id])}`.

Comment: If you are sure `AS` can be used even in where clause, then `Order.select('amount FROM line_items').where(['WHERE employee_id = ? AS employee_line_items', params[:employee_id]])` it's perfectly fine, you should avoid `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize` at all costs, it's not just a matter of security, `?` ensures rails generates prepared statements which are very optimized on the database side. `where(['SQL', param1, param2])` the `SQL` part can contain basically any valid sql available in `WHERE` clause